# In Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 why is the background image CSS crossed out in the Datatables header?

Tags: css, datatables, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to have images show in an extended width Datatables header. The styling is using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 framework. Can anyone tell why this CSS is crossed out in this below image ? ( please check  link to site http://iprobesolutions.com/test2  [image: CSS] which is using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3

The background images show up fine in this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/0s405fyf/)

I've been trying to strip elements one by one but just can't figure out what's wrong with the CSS.

This is an example of the CSS for the background image:

```
table.table1 thead .beyer, 
#example table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc .beyer  {
background-image: url("https://placehold.it/264x140.jpg") no-repeat center        `center;
 height:264px;
 width:140px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 height: 10rem;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: crossed out means overridden. meaning there is a rule somewhere in your CSS that is taking precedence.

Comment: Thanks yes I had read about that but I can't locate in my code what is causing the issue.

Comment: Search all your code for those rules and see where it is duplicated.

Comment: @scoopzilla tx for encouraging me to look further. I believe I found what's causing the issue and will be posting new question more specific to how to solve the matter now that I know what's apparently wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/images/sort_both.png" are already taking up space in the header and preventing the placehold.it images to show. When you uncheck the former, the latter starts to properly show [image: per below red arrows in image]

Comment: You can accept your own answer as well. I would recommend doing so. :)